# npm package to read PDF buffer without creating the file?

Tags: javascript, npm, package

I'm looking for a npm package similar to word extractor for docx which can read docx buffer without creating the file, to do the same thing for pdf files. All of the ones I found require an existing file to function, and can't work on the buffer. Would like a suggestion!

Comment: Use ```multer``` or ```busboy```. Multer is built upon busboy, so using either will suit your requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for. How would I convert the buffer to text through them?

Comment: @KJ Is there no package which can handle that? I'm not quite sure what I need to do.

Comment: Could you give an example on how to use the hard drive cache for it? I never really dealt with that